# <error: illegal access> in chrome.runtime.sendMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm not able to build a working exchange messages beetween the current_script and the background. 
The error message is:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
at chrome-extension://lanofchlikjdallgfmhbbijdglepcomm/script.js:29:23
at <error: illegal access>
at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:356:21)
at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:342:27)
at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:362:17)
at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect (miscellaneous_bindings:258:27)
```

I worked with the Google API [Simple one-time requests](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and had the following constellation:

**mainfest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Facebook Cage",
  "description": "Facebook Cage hilft dir den Inhalt deiner Facebook Seite anzupassen.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "https://facebook.com/",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**script.js**

```
document.onclick = function (){
  if(document.URL=="https://www.facebook.com/"){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
    });  
  }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('url', function(result) {
  !!result['url'] ? $("#input-area").val(result['url']) : "";
});

$("#save").click(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'url': $("#input-area").val()});
  window.close();
  return(false);
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Perhaps you can help, thanks!

Edit: 
The problem was in the manifest logic. I had three components: the popup.js and the script.js. The popup.js was embedded in the popup.html. The script.js as the content script. What have missed was a background logic, like a backgorund.js. Just put the code

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

in a background.js and link it in the manifest via

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

All in all, i finally delete the background login in the background.js, from there a storage getter was also possible.